# Unable to run docker image with an app in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, docker, docker-image

I am following the docker tutorials from the docker website (**https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/**) and trying to run an app (app.py - code given below) after building the image "friendlyhello". However when I try to run the app, I get the below error. I guess it is something to do with the code (app.py)

I have built the docker image successfully. However when I try to run the app which is to display the output in the browser, I get an error as 
       **Name error: name "null" is not defined** as shown in the screenshot below

[image]
I believe this because of the json format of the app.py which has a parameter execution_count and value as null. I understand pYthon has "None" but when I manually change it run, it still throws the same error

> App.py - from the tutorial website

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
 redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, 
 socket_timeout=2)

 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route("/")
 def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
    v   isits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
       "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
       "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), 
  hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

> JSON format - autogenerated - I only have Jupyter notebook and don't have pycharm in my system to open it. Not sure whether how is this json format generated.

[image]

I expect the output to be able to run the docker image and see the output as shown in the image below

> Output

[image]

Comment: I 've managed to complete the tutorial you provided. So the instructions are valid. You have probably missed something. I would recommend to start over from the beginning or include on you OP the steps you have followed along with the output of each step(build,run).

Comment: @leopal - Everything is going for me except that app.py. I just copied the same code from tutorial and put it in app.py. As I don't have pycharm/editor, I pasted it in notepad and saved it as .py file. I don't know how is this code represented in json. Is your code converted to json?

Comment: Am I making any mistakes any while saving the file in .py format?

Comment: Wait, do you mean that the contents of  `app.py` is the json you have provided? If yes, this is why you are unable to run the container. The contents of the `app.py` should be the same as in the provided link. I neither have python on my pc, I created an `app.py` and pasted the contents with sublime. Maybe try with another text editor.